# Which hierarchical model is most appropriate for my data?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis

I would like to ask your opinion about the best way to model my problem:

- I have patient-level data on hospital spending per year, along with
  patient-level information (hospital id, hospital specialty, age, sex, prior hospital use...etc.)
- In addition, I have a variable on the hospital-level indicating whether or not the hospital was contracted by the insurer that year (contract=1 if contracted)

I would like to run a fixed effects-type of analysis to **see how a change in the contract type affects average spending per patient. I would like to see this broken down by specialty.** Unfortunately, there is no patient in my dataset that received treatment both before and after a contract-type changed. Therefore, I am forced to evaluate change in average patient spending per hospital (and specialty).

My initial starting point was a fixed effect:

```
fe <- plm(avgspend ~ contract *as.factor(specialty), index=c("hospital_id), data=dat, model="within")
```

but this gives me an error, as I have more than one observation per hospital_id and time. So the solution has to be some kind of a multi-level setup. I am using [this](http://www.rensenieuwenhuis.nl/r-sessions-16-multilevel-model-specification-lme4/) website to familiarize myself with multi-level modelling but I am confused about which model would best fit my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mixed effects model to fit a 2-level model to these data. It would look something like this:

```
lmer(avgspend ~ contract * specialty + (1 | hospital_id), data = mydata)
```